# Advice: Getting around WebLogic t3

Tags: java, oracle, weblogic12c

The company that I work for has a Api deployed on weblogic server thats been around for 15 years. There are around 250 apps that depend on this API. The challenge we are facing to upgrade the API or to remove it from Weblogic and upgrade is because of the t3 url that all the apps rely upon. From what i heard its impossible for all apps to change their implementation. Is there any way of getting around t3 or is this api stuck with t3 protocol for life?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to update the service provider, but not change any of the existing client applications?  I guess you could always implement a bridge in a WLS instance that listens for requests using the "old" RMI/T3 based protocol, and translates them into requests for whatever new implementation you want to use (and then translates the responses back into RMI/T3 responses for those existing clients).

Or you could change the actual URL (which must be externalized into something like a properties file, not embedded in the code, right?), and then port or implement an RMI-based solution using something other than WLS T3 behind the scenes.  Ideally,  your clients ought to be able to pick up the stubs for the new implementation (assuming the same interfaces are maintained), and use them instead of the original T3 stubs.

Comment: Very interesting challenge. The solution proposed by @moilejter is quite tricky. T3 is a binary protocol and its specification is not public i think. Moreover, It embeds technical and complex functionalities such as failover, load balancing, transaction management and security... 
If your problem is "just" a routing problem of urls from the clients, you can use an HAProxy server in front of WebLogic. HaProxy can work at the TCP level and then is able to handle T3 traffic from clients to weblogic server instances.

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin That is why I suggested implementing the brigde in a WLS instance :-) - that way, the bridge developer would "only" have to build an RMI server based on the existing interfaces, and let WLS provide the T3 implementation behind the scenes (as it does for the current solution).  Without a WLS instance, I think you're right it would be impractical...

Comment: Thank you both for advice. Can you pls help me with providing a link that explains how to implement this kind of bridge in a wls instance.

Comment: A link explaining how to set up an RMI service: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/java-rmi-registry/ - you would need to find the interface that the T3 client of yours is using, then implement that interface in a Java class you'd write, that would implement each method of the interface by calling whatever replacement service you want to use instead, then gets the return value from that and converts it into the return value expected by the original interface, which you'd then return to the original client...

Comment: A link on using the WebLogic RMI implementation: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/e13721/toc.htm